# Insert or update a record without first querying?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Let's say my web service gets some data like record id and other column values.

Is there a way I can insert or update this database record like `AddOrUpdate(TEntity)` method do, but without first querying? Unfortunately `AddOrUpdate(TEntity)` first makes select query to database.

Comment: How do you want to update a record without finding it?

Comment: You can do that. You can attach your object to your context and set its state to Added or Modified. When you then save changes, the corresponding INSERT/UPDATE statement will be sent.

Comment: Yeah. Now how do you know the state without asking? It is possible in one sql statement with some not exactly complex programming, but EF can not do it this way and does not generate a "no round trip upsert style command". I understand you want to propose a magical unicorn solution - the problem with that one is: it does not work.

Comment: You know the state quite easily: OP described that he does retrieve the record id. if it is a valid id, then it is to be updated. if it is not valid like outside the ID's constraints, for example negative, the object has to be added. The new id is then computed either by the db or, if there is no autoincrement, by a single db call like you suggested. I understood this was common knowledge (a co-worker suggested it a few years ago after researching online), but I guess it is not so this should clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

No.

That is not how Entity Framework works. Yes, SQL supports that, but no, EF does not. To change an object you need to have it first, which is a read operation.

Upserts - require the test to make sure the data is there or not. Yes, not optimal, but that is how it is.

Comment: this is not true. try having a table without autoincrement on PK position, and attach a new object to a new context with an already existing PK and added state, which will cause a id not unique exception, while attaching an object with not existing pk in modified state will lead to a 0 rows were affected statement. querying the data before inserting or updating is not necessary for EF, it's a pure ORM in this regard.